# WITH RECURSIVE only returning the non-recursive term

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a table `object` consisting of the following fields:

- `id`: the record id
- `idobject_parent`: the parent of the object
- `label`: an arbitrary string describing the object

The table content is constructed so that every object has a parent, except the top node for a tree that has an `idobject_parent` value of `null`. There are many trees, each with a different top node.

Given a leaf node, I want to get the fields of the top node for that tree. So I have the following query:

```
with recursive parent_object(id) as (
        select id,idobject_parent, label from object o
    union
        select oe.id, oe.idobject_parent, oe.label from object oe join parent_object pc on (oe.id = pc.idobject_parent) where oe.idobject_parent is not null
)
select id,idobject_parent,label from parent_object where id = 340;
```

Where `340` is an arbitrary leaf id I'm using for this test.

The problem is that this query just returns the leaf node itself, i.e., it seems to just execute the non-recursive case.

By manually doing the recursive query and using the result as "input" for the following one, I can see that I'm ascending the tree correctly:

```
 db=# select oe.id,oe.idobject_parent,oe.label from object oe join (select 340 as id,480 as idobject_parent, 'hello' as label) as pc on (oe.id = pc.idobject_parent) where oe.idobject_parent is not null;
 id  | idobject_parent |   label
-----+-----------------+-----------
 480 |             105 | xxxxxxx
(1 row)

 db=# select oe.id,oe.idobject_parent,oe.label from object oe join (select 480 as id,105 as idobject_parent, 'hello' as label) as pc on (oe.id = pc.idobject_parent) where oe.idobject_parent is not null;
 id  | idobject_parent |         label
-----+-----------------+-----------------------
 105 |             102 | yyyyyyy
(1 row)

 db=# select oe.id,oe.idobject_parent,oe.label from object oe join (select 105 as id,102 as idobject_parent, 'hello' as label) as pc on (oe.id = pc.idobject_parent) where oe.idobject_parent is not null;
 id | idobject_parent | label
----+-----------------+-------
(0 rows)
```

What's wrong with my query? Why am I not getting this?

```
 id  | idobject_parent |         label
-----+-----------------+-----------------------
 105 |             102 | yyyyyyy
(1 row)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your first part of the union should have some condition for the root node. E.g. `where idobject_parent is null`

Comment: You should put your `where id = 340;` termination condition in the non-recursive leg, and work in the other direction (extending the path upwards, towards the root node(s))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, nope, that just returns nothing (of course, if that's the first thing that gets executed, the first round already returns nothing and the with statements returns nothing. Am I understanding the construct wrong?)

Comment: @joop `id = 340 ` is just a placeholder, this will go inside a bigger query where 340 is not a fixed value. What do you mean by 'extending the path upwards'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending the forest downwards (starting with all the roots), you can walk upwards, towards the root. (this is also more efficient, since you dont have to generate all the paths before selecting the one you want)

```
-- sample structure
CREATE TABLE thetree
        ( id INTEGER not null primary key
        , parent INTEGER references thetree(id)
        -- , label text
        );

        -- make some data
INSERT INTO thetree(id,parent)
SELECT gs, gs / 3 FROM generate_series(0,20) gs;
UPDATE thetree SET parent = NULL where parent=0;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON thetree(parent,id);

-- SELECT * FROM thetree;

WITH RECURSIVE zzz AS (
        SELECT COALESCE(parent,id) AS root
        , parent AS par
        , id AS me
        , 0::integer AS upsteps
        FROM thetree WHERE id = 17
    UNION ALL
        SELECT COALESCE(t.parent,zzz.root) AS root
        , t.parent AS par
        , zzz.me AS me
        , 1+ zzz.upsteps AS upsteps
        FROM thetree t
        JOIN zzz ON zzz.par = t.id
        )
SELECT *
-- SELECT root,me
FROM zzz
WHERE zzz.par IS NULL -- eliminate partial paths
        ;
```

---

FYI The *downward* treewalk:

```
    -- treewalk; starting with roots: downward
WITH RECURSIVE omg AS (
        SELECT id AS root
        , id AS me
        , 0::integer AS upsteps
        FROM thetree WHERE parent IS NULL -- this is the root of a tree
    UNION ALL
        SELECT omg.root AS root
        , t.id AS me
        , 1+ omg.upsteps AS upsteps
        FROM thetree t
        JOIN omg ON t.parent = omg.me
        )
SELECT *
FROM omg
WHERE omg.me = 17
        ;
```

Comment: This works. I don't understand how, but it does. But how do I parametrize it so that the id is not 17 but an arbitrary one?

Comment: is it wrong to remove the `where` from the first clause and append to the query `and zzz.me = 17`? I mean, it works, but I wanted to make sure it's correct.

Comment: If you make the *me selection* afterwards, you could use the "downward" tree-traversal (which is less efficient, because it may have to explore the entire forest, before the final selection can be made) In the downward tree walk, you **have** to seed with *all* the roots ( := nodes with parent_id IS NULL)

Comment: `... and append to the query and zzz.me = 17?` Is is not incorrect, but the first part of the union would yield **all** the records from the table and the final condition would have to filter all-but-one out.